# Rails unexpectedly creating duplicated records

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I need to create a new market "3.5" when the "0.5" closed. The problem is, for some reason, many times, and only on the live server it created duplicaded "3.5", exactly at the same time when it closed the 0.5 and opens the first 3.5. Is there any way to prevent duplicated records from being created? The majority of times it creates single records, but for some reason I can't figure out, sometimes it messes up.

Here is part of the problematic code:

```
    ######CLOSE 0.5 / OPENS 3.5
    if self.markets.find_by_name('0.5') != nil then
      if result.sum >= 1 && (self.markets.find_by_name('0.5').status == "live" || self.markets.find_by_name('0.5').status == "pre-live")
        if self.markets.find_by_name('0.5').settle_temp.to_i == 6

          selection = "Over 0.5 Goals"

          if self.markets.find_by_name('0.5').status == "live" || self.markets.find_by_name('0.5').status == "pre-live"
            self.markets.find_by_name('0.5').close(selection)
          end
          if self.markets.find_by_name('3.5') == nil then
            self.markets.create!(name: "3.5", status: "live")
          end

        else
          self.markets.find_by_name('0.5').increment!(:settle_temp)
        end
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know your exact situation, but maybe you could add unique constraint
on name and event_id fields pair? For example in the migration you could write:

```
add_index :markets, [:event_id, :name], :unique => true
```

In this way you'll be sure that there is just one `markets` record with desired `name` value.

Comment: The "problem" is that market names are not unique. They are just unique for each "event_id" (another attribute of the table). Because of that reason your solution is not possible. I removed the create! and placed "create" instead. Let's see if it doesn't duplicate with the verification (i think the "!" skips that right?)

Comment: You can mark question as answered not to confuse future readers :)